# How to get cursor for API 28

Tags: kotlin, cursor, android-9.0-pie

I use this code to get cursor:

```
private fun getMediaCursor(
        uri: Uri,
        projection: Array<String>,
        dateColumnName: String,
    ): Cursor? {
        val sortOrder = "$dateColumnName DESC"
        return context.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, sortOrder)
```

it works fine for API29, but for API28 it always returns null. How can I resolve it?